# Using lists to find solutions

Tags: python, list

I am trying to produce code that will first find me all the perfect squares under `modulos p`, in a function `perfectsq(p)`.

With that list of perfect squares. I want to find all solutions of the equation `y^2=x^3+Ax+B`. I am doing this by using the list in `perfectsq(p)` to check that `m=x^3+Ax+B` is in that list. Can someone tell me why this code isn't compiling?

```
def perfectsq(p):
    x=[]
    for i in range(1,p):
        m=(i**2)%p
        x.extend(m)
        i+=1


def ellipticpt(a, b, p):
    x=perfectsq(p)
    if 4*(a**3)+27*(b**2) != 0:
        for i in range(0,p):
            m=(i**3+a*i+b)%p
            if m in x:
                i=x.index(m)+1
                print (m,i)
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
    else:
        print "Error"
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: If you're in Python 3+ `print` requires parenthesis: `print("Error")`.

Comment: ================================
>>> 
>>> ellipticpt(8,7,73)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ellipticpt(8,7,73)
  File "C:\Users\Alexandra\Anaconda\Scripts\Alexandra\Problem Set C Code", line 54, in ellipticpt
    x=perfectsq(p)
  File "C:\Users\Alexandra\Anaconda\Scripts\Alexandra\Problem Set C Code", line 50, in perfectsq
    x.extend(m)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 5):

> perfectsq x.extend(m) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

You can't `.extend()` a list with a single number argument, it's for extending a list with another list. Use `.append()` to add to the end of a list instead.

Also perfectsq() doesn't return anything

Try:

```
def perfectsq(p):
    x=[]
    for i in range(1,p):
        m=(i**2)%p
        x.append(m)
        i+=1
    return x


def ellipticpt(a, b, p):
    x=perfectsq(p)
    if 4*(a**3)+27*(b**2) != 0:
        for i in range(0,p):
            m=(i**3+a*i+b)%p
            if m in x:
                i=x.index(m)+1
                print (m,i)
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
    else:
        print "Error"
```